# Почему в функции при объявлении переменной, она располагается по адресу передаваемого параметра

Tags: c, стек

Oбъясните мне, пожалуйста, этот момент: При повторном вызове функции переменная `new` располагается ровно по тому же адресу что и `S->top`.

Почему это так работает и как нужно сделать правильно?

```
struct list{
    int val;
    struct list *prev;
};

struct stack{
    unsigned len;
    struct list *top;
};

void push(struct stack *S, int val){
    struct list new;
    new.val = val;
    if (S->len == 0){
        new.prev = NULL;
    } else{
        new.prev = S->top;
    };
    S->top = &new;
    S->len += 1;
}
```

Comment: Так работает выделение памяти в стеке, это нормально. Ваша проблема в том, что `new` перестает существовать, как только вы выходите из функции `push()`. Используйте `struct list *new = malloc(sizeof(struct list));` и тогда структура будет существовать даже после выхода из функции.

Comment: большое спасибо, упустил из вида этот факт.